# Powershell not displaying every node in xml

Tags: xml, powershell

I trying to display every child node in an XML file but some nodes are not getting displayed. Below is my powershell script.

```
$dst_web_config = "C:\Users\vel\web.config"
$src_web_config = "f:\Script_test\web.config"

# Creating XML objects for live and integration
$src_xml = New-Object -TypeName XML
$dst_xml = New-Object -TypeName XML
$src_xml.Load($src_web_config)
$dst_xml.Load($dst_web_config)

# Check nodes available
$src_top_node = $src_xml.DocumentElement.Name
$dst_top_node = $dst_xml.DocumentElement.Name

# Defining recursive function
function compare_nodes($node)
{
    if ($dst_xml.$dst_top_node.$node.HasChildNodes)
    {
        $dst_xml.SelectNodes("$dst_top_node/$node/*") | Select-Object -Expand Name | % {
            $xpath_node = [string]$node + "/" + [string]$_
            $path_node = [string]$node + "." + [string]$_
            write-host $path_node
            compare_nodes($path_node)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        #write-host "No Child found for" $node
        return
    }
}

if ($src_top_node -eq $dst_top_node)
{
    if ($dst_xml.$dst_top_node.HasChildNodes)
    {
        #write-host "Child Node exist for " $dst_top_node
        $dst_xml.SelectNodes("$dst_top_node/*") | Select-Object -Expand Name | % {
        compare_nodes($_)   
        }
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "No child nodes for "$dst_top_node
    }
}
else
{
    write-host $src_top_node" is not present in destination file"
}
```

I am putting some sections of XML file where all child nodes are not getting displayed.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="siteMapConfiguration" type="NRI.Helpers.Configuration.SiteMapConfiguration, NRI.Helpers" />
    <section name="promotionCategoriesSection" type="NRI.Helpers.Configuration.PromotionCategoriesConfigurationSection, NRI.Helpers" />
    <section name="BaseRestExtensions" type="domino.Web.BaseRest.Configuration.BaseRestSection, domino" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="townSearchSection" type="NRI.Helpers.Configuration.SearchConfigurationSection, NRI.Helpers" />
    <section name="userTypesSection" type="NRI.Helpers.Configuration.UserTypesConfigurationSection, NRI.Helpers" />
  </configSections>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="127.0.0.1" userName="username" password="password" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

In script output I am not getting "sectionGroup", "smtp" from above xml. These are two typical examples. How can I make sure script displays all the child nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problems

There are several things going on here.

First, when I run with your code, I am getting the `sectionGroup`. However I see it appearing as `configSections.system.web.webPages.razor` because the node has a name and you are using `Select-Object -Expand Name` in your pipeline.

Second, although it's not causing an issue, your function calling syntax is incorrect. `compare_nodes($_)` should be `compare_nodes $_` and `compare_nodes($path_node)` should be `compare_nodes $path_node`. If you add more arguments, this will really mess you up because `myfunc($a, $b)` is very different from `myfunc $a $b` in PowerShell.

Finally, your algorithm is not working in the case of `smtp`, because you have an element with a `.` in the name. When you recurse with `$node` equal to `"system.net.mailSettings"` your test of `HasChildNodes` fails.

```
if ($dst_xml.$dst_top_node.$node.HasChildNodes)
```

is evaluating to this:

```
if ($dst_xml.$dst_top_node."system.net.mailsettings".HasChildNodes)
```

instead of:

```
if ($dst_xml.$dst_top_node."system.net".mailsettings.HasChildNodes)
```

You can test it by just running the following:

```
$dst_xml.$dst_top_node."system.net.mailsettings"
$dst_xml.$dst_top_node."system.net".mailsettings
```

### Solution

Rewriting this is non-trivial. I would suggest using the XmlNode objects themselves and then passing along a second argument with the path (just for your output). For example,

```
function compare_nodes($node, $fullpath) {
    $node.ChildNodes | % {
        # build up $new_fullpath from $fullpath here
        compare_nodes $_ $new_fullpath
    }
}

if ($dst_xml.$dst_top_node.HasChildNodes) {
    $dst_xml.$dst_top_node.ChildNodes | % {
        compare_nodes $_ $dst_top_node
    }
}
```

Comment: That I can do if I know how many nodes are there. I have to list out all nodes in a file for which I don't know how deep the structure is.

Comment: Yeah, I see my answer is useless in that case. Any reason you can't use `Compare-Object $(Get-Content C:\Users\vel\web.config) $(Get-Content f:\Script_test\web.config)`? I'm trying to get a sense of what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: These two files belong to different environments. I am trying to compare them at node level. Requirement is each node has to present in both the files, their value might vary depending on environment.

Comment: Thanks Swoogan for investing your time. In the solution you provided, where are we checking whether we have reached bottom of the node chain (no further child nodes) or not? Are you asking to put that check along with new_fullpath creation logic?

Comment: As long as you are only using `Write-Host` and not returning anything, you don't need to. In your initial code the `else { return }` is redundant; the function returns without it. In my case, the function returns when its done processing the `ChildNodes` or there are none to process in the first place.